# What does the endomorphism group of an object tell us about the object in question?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

For example:

What conclusions can be drawn about the relations between two objects with the same group of endomorphism?

Can we tell from End(A) if A is Abelian or not?

Does End(A) contain information about the sub-objects of A?

Any information or references to information about this is highly appreciated.

Comment: So $A$ is a group?

Comment: Groups, Rings, Modules.. Any algebraic structure over which a group or ring of endomorphisms make sense. I saw from the book Wagner linked to that these include categories, but alas I am not that advanced yet.

Comment: End(A) can also tell you about whether or not A splits as a direct sum, which is fun to know.

Comment: If "groups" are the things where you can multiply and divide, then "additive categories" are just the things where End(A) is a ring.  Nice additive categories have the property that their objects are modules, and End(A) is exactly the ring of module endomorphisms.  Probably for you then, you can just stick to modules.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For abelian groups, the ring End(A) is very important.  As far as non-abelian groups A go, End(A) is not even (usually considered) a group.

"Adding" homomorphisms doesn't work in the non-abelian case.

If you define (f+g)(x) = f(x) + g(x), then (f+g)(x+y) = f(x+y) + g(x+y) = f(x) + f(y) + g(x) + g(y), but (f+g)(x) + (f+g)(y) = f(x) + g(x) + f(y) + g(y).  To conclude that:

f(y) + g(x) = g(x) + f(y)

are equal, you use that + is commutative, that A is abelian.  More precisely, if you take f=g to be the identity endomorphism, then f+g is an endomorphism iff A is abelian.

"Composing" homomorphisms doesn't work to form a group, since they are not invertible.

Aut(A), the group of invertible endomorphisms, does form a group.  Aut(A) does not determine if a group is abelian or not: 4×2 and the dihedral group of order 8 have isomorphic automorphism groups.

Instead of a ring, End(A) sits inside the "near-ring" of self-maps.  See [the wikipedia article on nearring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearring#Mappings_from_a_group_to_itself) for an explanation.

Comment: Thank you, that was a really nice answer.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a partial answer (although it uses the ring structure on the set of endomorphisms). A torsion abelian group is cyclic if and only if any two elements in $End(A)$ commute with respect to composition (in other words, $End(A)$ is a commutative ring).

http://www.springerlink.com/content/m72222448q6j7327/

There is a whole book on this subject: [Endomorphism rings of abelian groups](http://books.google.com/books?id=iy4sVSgzrvYC&printsec=frontcover&dq=endomorphism+rings+of+abelian+groups).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Do you know if anything useful can be said about non-abelian structures as well. It seemed to me like the book you referenced focuses on commutative structures alone.

Comment: @Feydarkin: well, the title tells you so!

Comment: @Feydarkin: Sorry, I did not have anything useful to add, but I think Jack Schmidt answers your question very well.

Comment: The link to `springerlink.com` is broken. I am not able to find a copy on the Wayback Machine, either.